# Pyspark and using UDFs: How to Pass Python Arguments (sys.argv, argparse) to Python Worker?

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm running a script via spark-submit as a standalone application, using Spark 3.0.1 and Python 3.6.8:

```
spark-submit [spark-confs]  pyspark-script.py --args1 val1 --args2 val2
```

and the script runs fine. Using argparse I am able to pick up args1 and args2, However, when I introduced a UDF to my script:

```
   my_udf = udf(lambda x: my_func(x))
   df = df.withColumn(cat, my_udf(cat))
```

I get the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.PythonException:
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/zoran/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark-script.py", line 24, in main
    with open(args.args1) as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I noticed my arguments stopped getting picked up. I confirmed this by hardcoding the values of arg1 and arg2 and it worked as before.

The question is, how do I pass python arguments to the underlying Python Worker?

In addition, what is happening with introducing an UDF that makes PySpark behave as such?

Edit:
There is an init_config() call that happens outside of the main script. It is not wrapped in `if __name__ == '__main__'` so it gets called automatically and it is designed to be called once. However, (1) it is being called again somehow by the Python Worker, which (2) errors out because it does not have access to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) says about the *application-arguments*

> Arguments passed to the main method of your main class, if any

This means that the arguments are only available in the context of Spark driver. As the udfs are executed on a remote executor in a remote Python process, they cannot access the arguments.

A way to transfer the arguments to the executor processes would be to use [broadcasts](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.Broadcast).

Comment: Interesting, I've also added an edit in an effort to understand how this call to the subsequent Python worker gets triggered as well. It may end up needing to be a separate question. Will do some more digging as well.